# Express rewrite URL issue

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to rewrite any query parameter of '?locale=en' to '/' and i don't want to redirect
in app.js i wrote before the router and it didn't work, the browser still has the same link.

```
var locale = req.query.locale;
var old_url = req.url;

if(locale=='en'){
 req.url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl.replace("/?locale=" + 
 locale,"");
 }

console.log('foo: ' + old_url + ' -> ' + req.url);
next();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use((req, res, next) => {

    let locale = req.query.locale;
    let old_url = req.url;


    if (locale == 'en') {
        req.url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}${req.originalUrl.replace(`?locale=${locale}`, "")}`
    }

    console.log('foo: ' + old_url + ' -> ' + req.url);

    next();

});


app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.end(req.url);
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Just remove the trailing/leading slash in the replace

```sh
foo: /my/path?locale=en -> http://127.0.0.1:8080/my/path
```

BUT: you are set with this code the `req.url` property to the whole path (incl. fqdn) and not only the url/path as its original purpose: https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url